# Django - Many to Many Relationship with Workouts & Exercises

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently stuck on how to do the following:

I want to track workouts and see the progress being made with the exercises.

Each workout has a name, body weight, date, and exercises.

I want to select the exercises when adding the workouts(exercises are already pre-created with a name and some tags), however, each workout is different, meaning the reps, sets, and weight for the exercise is different every time.

I'm not sure how to make a model for this.

I've added an image of a simple design I made to show what I'm after

Hope someone can help me, I'm pretty sure it's a simple solution however, my brain is stuck atm.

[Image Of Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY0UA.png)

Answer (score 1):

First an foremost, I'd recommend reading through the Django [models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/) to get an idea of what models represent and how they work.

To address your question, I think you've correctly identified all of the information you need to create your models, so let's go through them step by step.

### Architecture

It's helpful to take a step back and think about the entities in your app. Identify what they are, what attributes they posses and which of these attributes are [atomic](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php#:%7E:text=An%20atomic%20value%20is%20a,columns%20that%20are%20closely%20related.) i.e. cannot be their own entity.

- **Workout** - You mentioned that you want to track workouts with each one having name, body weight, date, and exercises. All of these attributes except for *exercises* seem to be atomic as they can be represented with fundamental datatypes (strings, floats, datetimes etc.). Moreover, one workout can have [many exercises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) indicating that we need to abstract it into its own entity.
- **Exercise** - You identified that exercises are pre-set and need to have a name and tags. A name is something we can represent with a string, however one exercise can have multiple tags, meaning it's not atomic (has a [one-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) relationship). This means we need to extract it into its own entity.
- **Tag** - From what you said, a tag simply has one attribute which is a name that can be represented by a string. One tag can belong to many exercises.

You may be wondering where we are storing the reps, sets and weight data for each exercise in each workout. This is actually going to require an extra entity that stores the many-to-many relationship between Exercise and Workout. Let's call this **Workout-Exercise**.

With this information we could draw a [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) as such:

[image: An ERD for the identified entities.]

This gives us what we need to start creating Django models.

### Models

Let's start with the `Exercise` and `Tag` entities. We can simply translate these directly into Django models:

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    
class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Here we've created the two models and specified a many-to-many relationship between `Exercise` and `Tag`. This means that an `Exercise` object can have many `Tag` objects e.g. you can call `exercise.tags.all()` to get all of the tags for a given `Exercise` object.

The tricky part comes when we are creating the `Workout-Exercise` entity. When we use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) in Django, it normally automatically creates a mapping model/table that we don't see. However, in the case where we want to store extra information about these relations (as we do in our use-case) we have to use a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

On this model we have to define the two foreign keys for the models we are linking along with the data types for the extra field data we want to store. In this case the foreign keys are `Workout` and `Exercise`, and the extra data are `reps`, `sets` and `weight`. The model definitions could therefore look like:

```
class WorkoutExercise(models.Model):
    workout = models.ForeignKey(
        'Workout',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(
        Exercise,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    reps = models.IntegerField()
    sets = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)


class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(
        Exercise,
        through=WorkoutExercise
    )
```

If you're confused about any of the model data type choices I've recommended, please take a look at [Django model docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/).

With this set-up you should be able to access and insert all of the data you need. If you need more information on how to access any of the many-to-many relationship data, please look at the Django [many-to-many docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many).

**Sources**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/
- https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many